# How to generate 4 random number and those 4 number sum must be 100

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want get 4 different random number and their total must be 100 (rN1+rN2+rN3+rn4=100)

Comment: Tip: Generate 3 random numbers only from 0-100, if total 3 is more than 100, generate again, the 4th is 100 minus other 3 :D I'd like to hear a better idea tho

Comment: Check this [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276206/method-of-generating-random-numbers-that-sum-to-100-is-this-truly-random) . It may help you to find a proper algorithm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just like this:

```
NSInteger r1, r2, r3, r4;
r1 = arc4random_uniform(96);
r2 = arc4random_uniform(97-r1);
r3 = arc4random_uniform(98-r1-r2);
r4 = 100-r1-r2-r3;
```

Comment: above gives some time 0 but, all number must be greater than 0, and total is 99 but i want must be 100

Comment: You can get rid of the warnings by using `unsigned int r1, r2, r3, r4;`

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is the easiest way to do this:

**1.** Generate 3 random number between 1 to 100.

**2.** Calculate the sum

**3.**  and generate 4th number as - Add the difference between calculated sum and 100.

Comment: What if first three number's sum is 115?

Comment: generate it again... means check weather sum is less than 100, if not generate it again.. OR we can take negative values well

Comment: in case of repetition, it may take too long to execute, but yes if we accept negative numbers then it is fine. But accepted answer is having a great logic. but thanks for the suggestions and try....

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL flag = false;
    int r,r1,r2,r3;
    while (!flag) {
         r = arc4random_uniform(100);
         r1 = arc4random_uniform(100);
         r2 = arc4random_uniform(100);
         r3 = arc4random_uniform(100);
        if (r+r1+r2+r3 == 100) {
            flag = true;
        }

    }
    NSLog(@"%d    %d    %d    %d",r,r1,r2,r3);
```

Comment: This have very less chance to happen and makes the cpu have to generate too many times, totally not efficent